# Store UTF-8 character in ANSI file [PHP][REGEX]

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

I need a regular expression match for an UTF-8 character, where my PHP file is an ANSI file.

```
$regex = "/Number:([\w\-]{0,100})<\/td>/";
```

The colon in the search-text is not an ordinary colon, it is a UTF-8 fullwidth colon. If my PHP file is also UTF-8 then I can just put the special character in and there is no problem. However, my PHP file is ANSI and I cannot change that because of constraints elsewhere.

What should the regular expression be to work?

A solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full width colon hex code is `FF1A`.

In PHP regex, you can use `\x{<HEX>}` notation in regex.

Thus, use

```
\x{FF1A}
```

To match a single `：`

Here is a [short demo](http://ideone.com/XICGEF):

```
$re = '/\x{FF1A}\w+/u';
preg_match($re, "：here 123", $m);
print_r($m); // => [0] => ：here
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. It is still not matching, I will need to study it more.

Comment: Are you using the `/u` modifier? It is important if you manipulate Unicode strings.